# Every thing, that has to do with libarys is deletet while Obfusing my Java Programm with Proguard?

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

i am trying to obfuse and Optimize/shrink my Programms with the free Obfuscator ProGuard. When i'm using it, I'm setting in-&output and then, leaving the default settings, Proceed. I get a errorlog like this everytime (This time i tryed to obfuse the videoplayer tutorial from oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/simpleplayer.htm and the next page):

```
HI! i am trying to obfuse and Optimize/shrink my Programms with the free Obfuscator ProGuard. When i'm using it, I'm setting in-&output and then, leaving the default settings, Proceed. I get a errorlog like this everytime (This time i tryed to obfuse the videoplayer tutorial from oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/simpleplayer.htm and http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/playercontrol.htm):

ProGuard, version 5.3
Reading program jar [D:\VideoPlayer.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\rt.jar]
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find superclass or interface             
javafx.application.Application
Warning: MediaControl: can't find superclass or interface    javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
Warning: MediaControl$1: can't find superclass or interface javafx.scene.layout.Pane
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find superclass or interface javafx.event.EventHandler
Warning: MediaControl$3: can't find superclass or interface javafx.beans.InvalidationListener
Warning: MediaControl$8: can't find superclass or interface javafx.beans.InvalidationListener
Warning: MediaControl$9: can't find superclass or interface javafx.beans.InvalidationListener
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.application.Application
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.application.Application
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class   javafx.stage.Stage
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.stage.Stage
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.Group
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.Group
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.Scene
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.Scene
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.Media
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.Media
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.Scene
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.stage.Stage
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.stage.Stage
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced method 'void launch(java.lang.String[])' in program class EmbeddedMediaPlayer
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.stage.Stage
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.stage.Stage
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.Group
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.Scene
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.Media
Warning: EmbeddedMediaPlayer: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced method 'void setStyle(java.lang.String)' in program class MediaControl
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaView
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaView
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.Pane
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.Pane
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.collections.ObservableList
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.collections.ObservableList
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.Pane
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced method 'void setCenter(javafx.scene.Node)' in program class MediaControl
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.HBox
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.HBox
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.geometry.Pos
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.geometry.Pos
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.HBox
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.geometry.Insets
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.geometry.Insets
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.HBox
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
 Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.HBox
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Label
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Label
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.Priority
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.Priority
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.HBox
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Label
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Label
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Label
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced method 'void setBottom(javafx.scene.Node)' in program class MediaControl
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.application.Platform
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.application.Platform
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaView
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Label
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.HBox
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
``Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.Pane
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Label
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Label
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Label
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Label
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl$1: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.Pane
Warning: MediaControl$1: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.Pane
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Label
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Label
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$10: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.event.EventHandler
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$Status
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$Status
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$Status
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$Status
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$Status
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$Status
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.event.ActionEvent
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.event.ActionEvent
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.event.ActionEvent
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$Status
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.event.Event
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.event.EventHandler
Warning: MediaControl$2: can't find referenced class javafx.event.ActionEvent
Warning: MediaControl$3: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.InvalidationListener
Warning: MediaControl$3: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.Observable
Warning: MediaControl$3: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.Observable
Warning: MediaControl$4: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$4: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$4: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl$4: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl$4: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$4: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl$4: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$4: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl$5: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl$5: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl$5: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl$5: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl$6: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$6: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$6: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.Media
Warning: MediaControl$6: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.Media
Warning: MediaControl$6: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$6: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$7: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl$7: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl$7: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl$7: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Button
Warning: MediaControl$8: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.InvalidationListener
Warning: MediaControl$8: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl$8: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl$8: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl$8: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl$8: can't find referenced class javafx.util.Duration
Warning: MediaControl$8: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$8: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$8: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$8: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$8: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.Observable
Warning: MediaControl$8: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.Observable
Warning: MediaControl$9: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.InvalidationListener
Warning: MediaControl$9: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl$9: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl$9: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.control.Slider
Warning: MediaControl$9: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$9: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$9: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$9: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
Warning: MediaControl$9: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.Observable
Warning: MediaControl$9: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.Observable
Warning: there were 196 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 4 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Note: you're ignoring all warnings!
Preparing output jar [D:\VideoPlayer2.jar]
  Copying resources from program jar [D:\VideoPlayer.jar]
```

If i Procced with ignoring the warnings and decompiling the result i get this:

import javafx.application.Application;

```
public class EmbeddedMediaPlayer
  extends Application
{
  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
  {
    launch(paramArrayOfString);
  }
}
```

Thats all. Nothing else. Why?

Comment: When you run the obfuscator, are the imported libraries your code refers to in the classpath?

Comment: I dont use external libarys. i use only the integrated javaFX libarys, so i dont have to set it, right?

Comment: JavaFX was only included from JDK 7 update 2 onwards. Is it possible your process is using an older JVM?

Comment: nope, i am running Build 1.8.0_101-b13